# AKS URL Rewrite Angular

Tags: angular, azure, azure-aks

AKS URL rewrite makes a 404 as it ignores the URL naming convention

When I access dev.dev.com/merchant, an Angular app, it will show a blank page. Checking console, it shows

> GET https://dev.dev.com/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dev-ingress
  namespace: dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.dev.com
    secretName: ssl
  rules:
  - host: dev.dev.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: dashboard
          servicePort: 80
        path: /merchant(/|$)(.*)
```

I'm expecting:

dev.dev.com/merchant/runtime.js and that the whole application runs fine with /merchant in the url.

Accessing the service via IP address directly is fine. Now sure what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, when you use a custom domain, then you need to use not only an nginx ingress controller but also need an HTTP route. If not, it shows the error 404.

If you just to do the test for a domain name, you can use the HTTP application routing that Azure provides, the steps in [HTTP application routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/http-application-routing). You can also create a subdomain for the Azure DNS with the public IP, and you can follow the steps in [Create an HTTPS ingress controller on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-tls).

Comment: How do I combine application routing and the ingress controller? The application is accessed via dev.dev.com/merchant

Comment: @user2172398 Actually, the application routing is just for the Azure DNS and you just can add a subdomain.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. I also reached out to the kubernetes nginx team but have been told that it's not possible: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4266

Comment: @user2172398 Well, the words that "NGINX can only rewrite the incoming traffic, changing the URL to the backend, it doesn't change the response from your application" is right. So if you have your own DNS, then Azure will help you to rewrite the access from your own DNS to the backend service. But if you want to change the response from the backend service, it's impossible.